# Removing table border which is inside a cell

Tags: css, border, parent-child

I have this table inside another table, i want to remove the border from the cells of child table(around A and B). 
Below is the source code for this.

```
    <style>
    .withBorders tr td{
       border: 1px solid black !important ;
    }
    .withBorders table.withoutBorders tr td {
       border:0px
    }
    </style>

    <table class="withBorders">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="withoutBorders">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

The problem is this isn't working, i have tried many changes with child table's css selector but i am unable to override parent table css property.

Could someone please advice on this?
Note: I can not make any changes to the parent table css selector.

Comment: remove !important in your first rule to start with :) , then maybe write a correct value for border :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .withBorders tr td{
       border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .withBorders tr td table tr td {
       border:none;
    }
```

```html
    <table class="withBorders">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="withoutBorders">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

1. repeat what you typed, don't change your typing like this

> ```
> .withBorders table.withoutBorders tr td {
>    border:0px
> }
> ```

2. avaoid !important in your css. it's not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the code like this:

```css
.withBorders tr td{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
.withBorders table.withoutBorders tr td {
   border:0px
}
```

```html
<table class="withBorders">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="withoutBorders">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

"!important" means that if it is some choice between 2 styles, it will be choosen the style with higher priority. (the style which contains "!important")

Comment: border:0px is not a valid value. you need at least the type of border, the type and color and finally size :)

Comment: @GCyrillus I'm sorry, but you seem to be mistaken. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Comment: @BDawg try to set border:10px; on itself, and tell me if it worked :) (canditate are not recommandation yet :) )

Comment: @GCyrillus It successfully applies the border width and is considered a valid value by the CSS specifications. Simply add a `border-style` property and the browser will know how to render it. See https://jsfiddle.net/hfso15b6/

Comment: @BDawg :) okay, so why is it not working on itself or if you only reset border-width (without border-width but with the short hand propertie ) ? do not misunderstand me.https://jsfiddle.net/hfso15b6/2/ a good answer is also made of good advise

Comment: also can you tell that you removed the !important value and why you removed it ... in your answer , no to me. see my comment under question :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Maybe we just have a miscommunication here. Using `border: 5px` will not accomplish anything visually by itself because it actually sets three different CSS properties: `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color`. By excluding the style and color, we are telling the browser to use some default values for those two properties. This means `border-style: none` gets used, which removes the border but keeps the `border-width` setting you provided. This is why setting `border-style` to anything except `none` afterwards retains the border width of `5px` as shown in my last fiddle.

Comment: @GCyrillus Then, to return to the original point, `border: 0px;` = `border: 0px none #000000;` = `border-width: 0px; border-style: none; border-color: #000000;` (assuming the element's `color` property is `#000000`)

Comment: **no it is not , else it would work**. You may think that specs tells you it works but it is not the way to do it  **I  repeat, you need at least to set the type of border in the shorthand property to emulate a border** border: 0px solid ; does work, border:XXunits; does nothing cause it is missing the basic style needed to draw a border ... so here in the case border:0px; is wrong and you are just lucky that he wants to remove the border. end of this thread for me :) . Take care